# Upload image to mysql server

Tags: java, php, android

Is there a way to upload image to my mysql database (Blob type) and make it for example like facebook, when i take a picture it appears a button in front of image so when i click it sends. All the tutorials that i found are like this: https://trinitytuts.com/capture-image-upload-server-android/
And i didnt want to take picture put it in a image view and then send i wanted to do it like i said. Is it possible to do? how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible.

[usign post](http://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/)

[usign post multipart](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/)

remember the backend for test.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! it is possible to save images in BLOB type, but it increases your database size. Hence I will suggest you to upload images to server and just save their path/URL in a database. You can retrieve images using that URL.

Saving images as a BLOB is not a good idea for large images.